# How to dump YAML with explicit references?

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

Recursive references work great in `ruamel.yaml` or `pyyaml`:

```
$ ruamel.yaml.dump(ruamel.yaml.load('&A [ *A ]'))
'&id001
- *id001'
```

However it (obviously) does not work on normal references:

```
$ ruamel.yaml.dump(ruamel.yaml.load("foo: &foo { a: 42 }\nbar: { <<: *foo }"))
bar: {a: 42}
foo: {a: 42}
```

I would like is to explicitly create a reference:

```
data = {}
data['foo'] = {'foo': {'a': 42}}
data['bar'] = { '<<': data['foo'], 'b': 43 }

$ ruamel.yaml.dump(data, magic=True)
foo: &foo
    a: 42
bar: 
    <<: *foo
    b: 43
```

This will be very useful to generate YAML output of large data structures that have lots of common keys

How is it possible without disputable re.replace on the output?

Actually the result of `ruamel.yaml.dump(data)` is

```
bar:
  '<<': &id001
    foo:
      a: 42
  b: 43
foo: *id001
```

So I need to replace `'<<'` with `<<` and maybe replace `id001` with `foo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create something like that, at least in ruamel.yaml ¹, you should use round-trip mode, which also preserves the merges. The following doesn't throw an assertion error:

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
foo: &xyz
  a: 42
bar:
  <<: *xyz
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
assert ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data) == yaml_str
```

What this means is that `data` has enough information to recreate the merge as it was in the output. In practise however, in round-trip mode, the merge never takes place. Instead retrieving a value `data['foo']['bar']['a']` means that there is no real key `'bar'` in `data['foo']`, but that that key is subsequently looked up in the attached "merge mappings".

There is no public interface for this (so things might change), but by analyzing `data` and looking at `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()` you can find that there is a `merge_attrib` (currently being the string `_yaml_merge`) and more useful that there is a method `add_yaml_merge()`. The latter takes a list of (int, CommentedMap()) tuples.

```
baz = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
baz['b'] = 196
baz.yaml_set_anchor('klm')
data.insert(1, 'baz', baz)
```

you need to insert the `'baz'` key before the `'bar'` key of data, otherwise the mapping will reverse. After insert the new structure in the merge for `data['bar']`:

```
data['bar'].add_yaml_merge([(0, baz)])
ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
foo: &xyz
  a: 42
baz: &klm
  b: 196
bar:
  <<: [*xyz, *klm]
```

( if you like to see what `add_yaml_merge` does insert

```
print(getattr(data['bar'], ruamel.yaml.comments.merge_attrib))
```

before and after the call)

If you want to start from scratch completely you can do:

```
data = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap([
    ('foo', ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap([('a', 42)])),
    ])
data['foo'].yaml_set_anchor('xyz')
data['bar'] = bar = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()
bar.add_yaml_merge([(0, data['foo'])])
```

instead of the `data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)`.

---

¹ <sub>Disclaimer: I am the author of that package.</sub>

Comment: Is there another way than `d = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(ruamel.yaml.dump(data))` to import a `dict` into a `round_trip` object?

Comment: @nowox To start "from scratch" you'll have to start with `data = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()` instead of `data = dict()` (and the same for any other dict you want to create underneath that has to keep keys ordered and allow for the extra data (reference names, comments, etc) to be attached).

Comment: @nowox I updated the answer with the complete code to get rid of the `round_trip_load()`

Comment: Thanks but this is not very convenient. My goal is to add a merge on an existing dict which is huge. Doing `data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)` is slower but much easier to do. With your example I need to recursively parse my data structure to create `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap` objects.